# Convert Google Doc to Docx using Google Script

Tags: ms-word, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

Is it possible to convert a Google document to a Word docx file programmatically using Google Script ?

Answer (score 9):

This should work

```
function myFunction() {

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  //Make sure to replace the correct file Id
  // Fetch the docx blob
  var blb = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<ID_of_Google_Document>&exportFormat=docx', 
                              {
                                headers : {
                                  Authorization : 'Bearer '+token
                                }
                              }).getBlob();

  //Create file in Google Drive
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blb).setName('<name_of_exported_file>.docx');

  //Put the file in a drive folder
  DriveApp.getFolderById('<FOLDER_ID>').addFile(file);

}
```

Comment: This solution works with the new Google API, instead of the other old answers.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [this item](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=585) on the issue tracker...

> You can convert a Google Document to docx today using the Drive
>   Advanced Service:
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive
>
> Here is a small example:

```
function convertToDocx(documentId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(documentId);
  var url = file.exportLinks['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];
  var oauthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
    }
  });
  return response.getBlob();
}
```

Comment: You've given a code example with `documentId` - does it (documentId) refer to the *documentId* in Drive or in Docs? How to distinguish? What if i want to save into docx a current document from google app scripts:

  `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()...`

Comment: the answer is: `var documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();`

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore with the new Google API.

Comment: Where does this save the new .docx file to?