# Exception: Blob object must have non-null data for this operation. (line 19)

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I'm trying to attach multiple Google Doc files from a folder to send to an Email. However, the above exception arises.

The code is as follows

```js
function email() {   

   // Get attachments folder
  var attachementFolderId = "xyz";
  Logger.log("Attachement Folder ID:  " + attachementFolderId)
  var getAttachementFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(attachementFolderId);

   // Get all files from the folder
 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(attachementFolderId).getFiles();
   
 //Get All attachments
   var attachements = [];
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   attachements.push(file.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS));
 }

  
     MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: email,
     subject: subject,
     attachments: attachements
    })
}
```

This code works fine if the file is either a pdf or a Microsoft Word doc but causes an issue for a Google Doc.

Comment: Unfortunately, `getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)` cannot be used. So when you want to retrieve the blob from Google Document. It is required to convert it to other mimeType. For example, when you want to convert it to PDF format, please modify `file.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)` to `file.getBlob()`. When you want to convert it to DOCX format, I think that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15636543/7108653

Comment: I wonder why App Script provides it as an option if it throws an exception? Thanks a lot! though. I would upvote the comment but I do not have enough rep points to do so.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When [the official document of `getAs(contentType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String))
  ) is seen, it says as follows.

  > The MIME type to convert to. For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. For images in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid.

  - In this case, unfortunately, `MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS` cannot be used for this.
- When you want to retrieve the blob from Google Document. It is required to convert it to other mimeType.

  - When you want to convert it to PDF format, please modify `file.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)` to `file.getBlob()`.
  - When you want to convert it to DOCX format, I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15636543/7108653) might be useful.

#### References:

- [getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String))
- Related question

  - [Convert Google Doc to Docx using Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15636543/7108653)