# Is there a way to convert .doc file to .docx file using docx library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a task which converting docx to html and the Mammoth library works well. However, I want to convert doc file to html but Mammoth doesn't support it. I tried to convert doc to docx using docx library but it didn't work
Here is the code that I tried

```
const docBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
const docString = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(docBuffer);
```

The result of docString is ��ࡱ� which is not what I'm expecting.
How can I get the string of doc file to pass it to the docx.Document method?

```
const docxFile = new docx.Document({
sections: [
    {
        properties: {},
        children: [
            new docx.Paragraph({
                children: [
                    new docx.TextRun({
                        text: "sadas" //here
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    }
]});
```

Comment: I believe there is no library that support convert doc to docx or doc to html well in js. Some afternative is using 3rd api or build your own service to convert it (with win32com). Another solution you can try is use google api to convert doc to docx [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41270548/20320398)

Comment: @dinhit thanks for your response. Your link is about convert google doc file to docx, not microsoft word document (.doc) file to docx

Comment: I believe there is some kind of google docs api able to do it, that SO answer for example. I used to upload doc file, convert it to docx and then download as docx file but manually.

Comment: You should also check [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert)